# How to access internet on an Apple iBook G3 without Airport Card?

Tags: mac, network, powerpc

I got an old Apple iBook ([second generation G3 if I'm not mistaken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBook#iBook_G3_Dual_USB_.28.22Snow.22.29)) without an Airport Card.

Are there any other options to access the internet on it besides the ethernet port?
Could I share the WiFi from a smartphone with the iBook or something like that?

Comment: Can you buy a USB wifi stick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is going to be tricky because any new usb wifi adapters are probably not going to have the driver support with the OS you are going to be using. 
(If you are right about the model the maximum OS is 10.4.11.)

[Amazon has original airport cards for sale](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=electronics&field-keywords=ibook%20g3%20airport%20card&rh=n:172282,k%3aibook%20g3%20airport%20card) and it looks like they aren't too expensive compared to newer adapters (~$20). That's the solution I'd use to get that computer online.

Comment: of course in that same search there is a G3 iBook with an airport card for $75, so I guess $20 does seem a little high.